# How to fake different document url in a SPA forGoogle Analytics

Tags: reactjs, google-analytics

My application is a SPA on which it is possible to "change page" by clicking on button. So for a regular user he has the impression of going to another page, but the url never changes and I would like it to stay exactly as is.

Is there some way to fake the Document location URL (dl) and the Document Title (dt) for every information sent to  Google Analytics ?

Answer (score 0):

You can send virtual page view.

Using GTM:

1. Create trigger 'History change'.
2. Enable all built-in variables from block 'History'.
3. Go to Preview Mode and learn what values have your 'history' variables when you 'change' page (you can use them as Titles or URLs).
4. Create GA page view tag using template, trigger - 'History change', in tag settings add values for variables `page` (URL) and `tittle`(*More settings -> Fields to set*); use ready values from 'history' variables, in case of there are no suitable variables, create custom variables type 'Lookup table' or 'RegEx table' and add there pairs key-value for using as key 'click text' for example.

Comment: Let's say that on my "second page" I fire other GTM action would those action be considered children of my pageView ?

Comment: @J.Lev No, event will not be children of your pageView. You can send virtual URLs with events as labels, for example.